# Android DatePicker with title

Tags: android

Hey folks,
I'm placing an android DatePicker on LinearLayout through xml

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/birthday"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and when it there it doesn't have that title with clock icon, Day of week, Day and month name with year ( ico Mon, 04 August, 2008), like it has if DatePicker is shown in dialog.
Does any body know how this info can be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those items are present in the datepicker dialog, you can add them manually in your layout if you want. The logic for updating them can be found in the source for datepicker dialog. But, why are you not using the datepicker dialog if you want datepicker dialog features?

Refer this example
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try to figure out from source. Why I'm not using dialog, because it's already nested in a custom preference dialog and won't be appropriate to call new dialog from dialog.